# Sorting a Lookup Column from Survey that pulls from Calculated Field SP 2010

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, sorting, survey

I'm looking for a way to sort a Lookup question in a survey that pulls from a calculated field. Specifically, I have it lookup a calculated field that combines the date and name from a list. I want the latest dated one to show up on top so the person filling out the survey doesn't have to select the latest one. So right now it's this:

```
2014-02-26 | Test 1
2014-02-27 | Test 2
```

But I want it to do this:

```
2014-02-27 | Test 2
2014-02-26 | Test 1
```

This is a monthly recurring survey so I always want the latest one to be on top. I'm aware there are ways to do it with Infopath on a regular form, but I see no options for a survey. Unfortunately I don't have SharePoint designer and this is for work so I'm limited to whatever I can do from the web interface or infopath.